# SQL performance tuning with EXPLAIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a big table *(~44 GB, 421631931 rows)*.

I'm attempting to optimize this type of SQL query:

```
SELECT fid, sid, dsc_entry, clstr_first_entry, date_part('epoch',start_time)::numeric(20,7) AS time_epoch
FROM frames
WHERE (sid = 1)
AND start_time <= to_timestamp('1471161210.776')
ORDER BY start_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

So far, I have set up index on the column `start_time`:

```
"idx_start_time" btree (start_time) CLUSTER
```

When I run `EXPLAIN`, I get this plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..0.92 rows=1 width=24)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_start_time on frames  (cost=0.57..19347837.35 rows=55108378 width=24)
        Index Cond: (start_time <= '2016-08-14 09:53:30.776+02'::timestamp with time zone)
        Filter: (sid = 1)
```

This looks good to me (note that I have never attempted to optimize databases this way before), but the query still takes about approximately 80 seconds to complete.

Can you please point out to me, how can I speed this up some more? (disk space is not an issue)

Thanks,
Petr.

Comment: Well, the `date_part` does no favour to the running time - are you sure it's needed?

Comment: @mszymborski Good suggestion, the `date_part` is used to facilitate easier date parsing in my C++ application (using libpqxx). I will attempt to find out if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT fid, sid, dsc_entry, clstr_first_entry, 
       date_part('epoch', start_time)::numeric(20,7) AS time_epoch
FROM frames
WHERE (sid = 1) AND start_time <= to_timestamp('1471161210.776')
ORDER BY start_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I would recommend an index on `frames(sid, start_time)`.

Comment: I already have a unique index on `frames(start_time, sid)`, but it doesn't seem to be used in the plan. Is there a difference?

Comment: @PetrMánek . . . There is a major difference.  The ordering of columns in the index is very important for some queries.  In this case, the equality condition is on `sid`, so for the best index, that should be the first key.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned something today. I will reindex and get back to you.

Comment: I have created the index, ran `ANALYZE` and `VACUUM ANALYZE` but there is no effect. The plan looks still the same. What could be wrong?

Comment: How many different values of `sid` take on?  Perhaps it is not very selective.

Comment: There are only about 20-30 unique values of `sid`. Is there a way to find out why the planner does not take advantage of the new index?

Comment: 20-30 unique values is a small number.  The index is not very selective.  However, I'm surprised that the `(sid, start_time)` index isn't used.

Comment: Can we find out why the planner doesn't use it? Also, I have created all my indices `CONCURRENTLY`. Could this have caused any problems?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the order by, because is the inverse of the index.
Try using:

```
CREATE INDEX ix ON frames (start_time DESC NULLS LAST);
```

The order by desc requieres an additional time to resort the data in a temp table.

Comment: This didn't occur to me. I will attempt to create the index. For due diligence, both `start_time` and `sid` are `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Ok, discart the "NULL LAST"; try with the rest ;P